# Bind DependencyProperty to Visibility in a Style

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

There is a boolean `DependencyProperty` in a control, named `IsRunning`, which indicates that the control is doing something. I want to create a `Style` with `Visibility` of this control set to Visible if `IsRunning == true`, or Collapsed if `IsRunning == false`.

The control can be used in a page like this:

```
<TheControl Style="{StaticResource MyStyle}" IsRunning="{Binding CategoryListLoaded}"/>
```

and the style I tried (I too have tried TemplatedParent instead of Self without luck):

```
<Style x:Key="MyStyle" TargetType="TheControl" >
    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsRunning, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
</Style>
```

With the above code i get a XamlParseException.
I don't want to set the visibility in the page, I want to control the visibility with the style, because I have many of these controls and only one style.

Comment: Can't you set the Visibility of the control in the PropertyChangedCallback of the IsRunning property? Or are there other reasons to use a style?

Comment: I am referencing this control from a .dll so I don't have access to the code.

Comment: Is "TheControl" a `UserControl`, or something else?

Comment: No it is a custom control, but rather complex, so I am not able to recreate the control by myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since IsRunning is a bool, have you tried adding visibility straight to the control

```
<TheControl Style="{StaticResource MyStyle}" IsRunning="{Binding CategoryListLoaded}" Visibility="{Binding CategoryListLoaded, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
```

Comment: I have considered this, but this would be the last solution. And in the end I wan't to know how to achieve this in a Style, if thats even possible.

Comment: After trying to find a solution, it seems this is not easy, so I think this would be it, and will mark it as asnwer.

Answer (score 2):

doing in Style binding is still not supported I think... but there is a good old article that has a helper as a solution! Read about it here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2010/11/10/the-taming-of-the-phone-new-settervaluebindinghelper-sample-demonstrates-its-usefulness-on-windows-phone-7-and-silverlight-4.aspx